# Converting Bootstrap Date Rangeslider to Angular Materials

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

I have a working date range slider built with bootstrap library in AngularJS but i want to be able to configure it to run with Angular Materials. I tried it with md-slider but it could not create ranges. I am using rz-slider directive for creating the directive.  here is the fiddle of the code working with bootstrap :

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/agamb/954eve2L/1619/

```
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal) {
var date1 = new Date(2017, 3, 1);
var date2 = new Date();
var day;
var dateArray = [date1];
while(date1 <= date2) {
    day = date1.getDate()
    date1 = new Date(date1.setDate(++day));  
    dateArray.push(date1);
}
$scope.slider = {
   minValue: dateArray[0],
  maxValue: dateArray[dateArray.length-1],
  value: dateArray[0], // or new Date(2016, 7, 10) is you want to use different instances
  options: {
    stepsArray: dateArray,
    translate: function(date) {
      if (date != null)
        return date.toISOString();
      return '';
    }
  }
};
});
```

**RZ-slider**
https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it fixed by updating the libraries and removing $timeout and $modal from the dependencies as they are for bootstrap. 
here is the updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rehan516/m0ygxvdj/

```
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ngMaterial','ngAnimate','ngAria']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
```